# React- Elegantly Toggle State Visibility

Tags: reactjs, flask, state, react-bootstrap-table

I'm currently trying to integrate my own column selector into the flask-bootstrap-table 3.0-beta2 package.  I found an example on the github in the issues section which is as follows:

```
export default class ColumnHideTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showModal: false, hiddenColumns: {} };
  }

  changeColumn(id) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({ hiddenColumns: Object.assign(this.state.hiddenColumns, { id: !this.state.hiddenColumns.id }) });
    };
  }
}
```

However, this will only show/hide the ID column unsurprisingly and the checkboxes for the other values are stuck with checked values and when clicked, only check/uncheck and hide/show the id column

I'm trying to work out a solution using computed variables and I've cooked up the following:

```
  setColumnState(column) {
    let columns = Object.keys(cyhyData[0])
    var o = {}

    for(let i=0; i < columns.length;i++) {
      if(column == columns[i]) {
        Object.defineProperty(o, column, {
          value: !this.state.hiddenColumns.column,
          enumerable: true
        })
        break
      }
    }
    return o
  }  

  changeColumn(column) {
    return () => { 
      this.setState({ hiddenColumns: Object.assign(this.state.hiddenColumns, this.setColumnState(column)) });

      console.log(this.state.hiddenColumns)
    };
  }
```

This correctly hides the columns, but obviously wont un-hide them.  How can I toggle !this.state.hiddenColumns.givenCol?

Is there perhaps a cleaner solution I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a solution for anyone who needs it.  It's not elegant, but it works :)  any suggestions to make this cleaner are welcome!

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { showModal: false, hiddenColumns: {} };
}

changeColumn(column) {
  return () => {
    var o = {}

    if(!this.state.hiddenColumns.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
      Object.defineProperty(o, column, {
        value: true,
        enumerable: true
      });
      this.setState({ hiddenColumns: Object.assign(this.state.hiddenColumns, o) });
    } else {
      this.setState({ hiddenColumns: Object.assign(!this.state.hiddenColumns, o) });
    };
  }
}

closeColumnDialog = (onClick) => {
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
}

openColumnDialog = (onClick) => {
  this.setState({ showModal: true });
}
```